# give a sprite its children's width

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to simulate window behavior in AS3, so I have a sprite I named "container" which contains children. One of them is a TextField, others are Sprites.
When I add the textfield in my container I'm glad to see this one's width is re-calculated. So, if my textField width is set to 50px, my container too. So my window simulation is working well.
But, when I add the others sprites, the width of my container does not change, so my window simulation is no more working well... Why is that please ? I can't find no explanation.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be a problem, as the width and height are always calculated based on the children position and sizes. This is taken from the ActionScript documentation:

> **DisplayObject > width:**
>
> Indicates the width of the display object, in pixels. The width is
>   calculated based on the bounds of the content of the display object.
>   When you set the width property, the scaleX property is adjusted
>   accordingly

There must be another problem, so maybe try posting your code, or reducing the problem down to a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is all my fault, I tried to get this work a couple of hours without be able to understand where the issue come from. I couldn't see that I only made a mistake by add an "added to stage" Event in some of those displayObject. Width and height were calculated after I put them in a window... Again, thanks, and sorry.